# Why is /24 used in /etc/network/interfaces when configuring static IPs?

Tags: networking, debian

My understanding is that 10.0.2.1/32 means 10.0.2.1 vs 10.0.2.1/24 means 10.0.2.1 to 10.0.2.255.

For example in `/etc/network/interfaces`, `/24` is used when configuring static IPs.

But in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`, `-d 10.0.2.0/24` means any IP in the `255.255.255.0` subnet... which equals 10.0.2.0 to 10.0.2.255 right?

Sorry for the newbie question... I am confused!

Comment: Thanks Michael, but that answer is for rocket scientist. Can someone please answer this like if I was 5? I’m sure others will be thankful.

Comment: That is the ELI5 explanation.

Comment: What about a ELI1 then?  Trust me Michael, I spend thousands of hours teaching technology to people... that answer is still to meta. But thanks for pointing it out... I will jump into the rabbit hole.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please see answers bellow and consider not closing this question.

Comment: Do you happen to know what a netmask is (eg 255.255.255.0)? If so, a /xx is an abbreviated way of writing a netmask

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for helping out. I do, but don’t understand why `/24` is used when configuring a static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/32` when targeting a single IP in iptables. Both use cases seemingly are for single IPs... Perhaps thats the part I don’t understand as Krackout pointed out in his answer.

Comment: The number after the / is equivalent to the number of 1s in the netmask, so /24 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 = 255.255.255.0 and similarly a /32 is 255.255.255.255.

Comment: In the case of the /24 it say this IP is part of this network, so its equivalent to saying this IP is X.X.X.X and its network is X.X.X.0 and its netmask us 255.255.255.0 all in 1 shortish statement. (All it doesn't have is a gateway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, 10.0.2.1/32 means that you set 10.0.2.1 on your network interface but you are alone, the whole network is just your IP.

On the other hand, setting 10.0.2.1/24 means that your IP is 10.0.2.1 and the IP range 10.0.2.0-10.0.2.255 is a known, familiar, reachable block of IPs; no gateway (that is, another network device) needed to reach it.

One real scenario of /32 subnet setting is in firewall rules, if you want just one IP to be allowed or blocked, not a range. In most cases typing just the IP in a firewall rule assumes /32. You wouldn't use it in a PC's network interface for everyday use.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Does this mean that using `/32` in `/etc/network/interfaces` would break connectivity to the rest of the network? Please see update question for context.

Comment: Yes, it would break connectivity. Regarding 10.0.2.0/24 in iptables rules: That actually means the 10.0.2.0-10.0.2.255 range ( .0 represents the network, .255 broacast - packet sent everywhere, they cannot be assigned to net devices). But 10.0.2.1/24 in `/etc/network/interfaces` is not the same; it means setting IP 10.0.2.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0 on the net interface.

Comment: So this is confusing in the context of `/etc/network/interfaces` vs iptables right? The `/` notation has different meaning.

Comment: No, it's not different meaning; you'll have to dive a bit to understand it. Remember, `.0` represents the whole network, it's not an ordinary IP. That's the difference. On the other hand, on other subnet masks, `/23` for example, `.0` can also be an ordinary IP, so be careful on assumptions! Not easy to explain further in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

When your `interfaces` file has something like `address 192.0.2.1/24`, that specifies the address and the "netmask" (in the form of the `/n` network prefix length) all in one go.

Previously, the `interfaces` file would have had separate `address 192.0.2.1` and `netmask 255.255.255.0` entries in that same situation.  It's simply a modernization to  consistently use the `/n` notation.